# FxLayout - Wrap checkboxes aligned/evenly

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-flex-layout

I have 7 checkboxes for the days of the week (`Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday`) in a `fxLayout` using `row`.

They should be evenly spaced and if the width becomes smaller, I want the checkboxes to wrap, whereas they should be aligned vertically (taking into account the different lenghts of the days).
So if two days are on the next line, the Checkboxes should align with the two days on the first line.

---

This is what I currently have (Checkboxes not aligning properly):

**app.component.html**

```
<div fxLayout="row row-reverse" fxLayoutAlign="start center" 
fxLayoutGap="1em">
  <md-checkbox checked="true" *ngFor="let day of availableDays">
    {{day}}
  </md-checkbox>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'material-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  availableDays = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];
}
```

Here the corresponding [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/YbTFbk5URpsMkLq73M1k?p=preview)

---

How would you achieve what I need?

Comment: Try using `fxLayoutWrap` and `fxFlex` in the checkboxes (plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/4fCIKF7pRhTMCfeaHT9p?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you, this gave me the correct hint. Setting a fixed size for `fxFlex` did the trick.